# How to increase the connect timeout on a SqlCommand?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have around 7000 rows in excel and I want send them to another local computer with linked server. I increased connect timeout in my connections but I get the same time again with no result.

```
SqlCommand cmd9 = new SqlCommand("insert into [" + ConString + "].Database.dbo.ExpressE select * from ExpressE", conn);
cmd9.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Error message is:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: set the `TimeOut` on the `cmd9.TimeOut = 60 * 120` for instance also learning how to use the `intellisense` you could see all of the Property's associated with the newly created `cmd9` object by typing `cmd9.` and hitting ctrl + space

Comment: Pls Write me an example of the code i should use!

Comment: Hi, I've made some minor changes to your question and title to improve the clarity a little. If you don't like the changes feel free to roll them back on the [revisions page](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39859966/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

The SqlCommand has a property [CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) that by default is set to 30 seconds. You can set it to a higher number of seconds, even set it to 0 if you want the command to wait forever if needed. The link to the MSDN includes an example about how to use that property.